# Angular // ng-select Use interpolation within a textarea on a text pulled from an array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, string, string-interpolation

Still in my very first days with Angular and ran into a problem i can't get my head around.
What I am trying to accomplish is sort of creating a way to have a persons name added to a message template.

The templates are loaded from a file like this

```
this.http.get('../../assets/templatefiles/customtemplates.json').subscribe(data => {this.templateArray = data as any [];
```

The structure of the JSON file is as follows

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Type": "SR Templates",
    "Name": "Message 1",
    "Body": "Some meaningful text here"
},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Type": "SR Templates",
    "Name": "Message 2",
    "Body": "Some more meaningful text here"
},
{
    "Id": 3,
    "Type": "GTFO Templates",
    "Name": "Message 3",
    "Body": "Guess what? Exactly, some even more..blahhh"
}]
```

All good so far. Then, in my template I use ng-select to create the dropdown list to display the options grouped by Type

```
<ng-select [items]="templateArray"
              bindLabel="Name"
              bindValue="Body"
              groupBy="Type"
              [(ngModel)]="selectedTemplate"
              >
    
        <ng-template ng-optgroup-tmp let-item="item">
          <strong>{{item.Id}}</strong>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
```

So far...working it seems. Templates are grouped by Type and show up in the drop down just fine.
Below the selection is a textarea in which the "Body" value is supposed to be displayed. Works fine as well, when selecting a template from the drop down the text shows fine in the textarea.

The problem I am facing is that there is an input field for the persons name the message will be send to.
I get the name as follows:

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="srcName" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name">
```

The bit confusing me is how to get/add the persons name to the message using interpolation?
I was hoping for something like just having to change the text in the JSON and adding the interpolation to it but apparently that does not work hehe.

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Type": "SR Templates",
    "Name": "Message 1",
    "Body": "Dear {{srcName}, Some meaningful text here"
}
```

I've been searching up and down, but am ultimately stuck and am desperate for a nudge in the direction I would have to go to actually get that name inserted in the textarea together with the template from the array...

Comment: Once you get `srcName` how do you decide in which object of the array you will make the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function that concatenates your selected template and the name in you input, like so:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.message = `Dear ${this.srcName}, ${this.selectedTemplate}`;
  }
```

And then you can add a button that executes this function:

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Now whenever you select the template you want and add the name you want to the input and click on submit button, you will get a concatenated message with the info you want.
Here is [a live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3a7f31?file=src/app/app.component.html) if you want more explanation.
In the live demo a used a normal HTML select, but it should work the same with angular material select.

##EDIT

If you need to put your `srcName` inside of your templates body, you will have to create a place holder in your template's body, something like:

```
"Guess what? Exactly {srcName}, some even more..blahhh"
```

instead of:

```
"Guess what? Exactly, some even more..blahhh"
```

Then you will have to change the `onSubmit` function:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.message = this.selectedTemplate.replace('{srcName}', this.srcName)
  }
```

I also added the changes to to the live demo.

Comment: Nice, that's going in a very good direction. Need to find a way to adapt that so i can have messages where the user name is like in the middle of the sentence :)

Comment: @Toto like in the middle of the template body ?

Comment: Yes. In theory the srcName can appear in different positions. Like for example "Hi srcName, I got your mail but couldn't get back to you earlier" or something like "Hi Jenny, Toto from TAC here and I got srcName with me on the phone for our Webex session.

Comment: @Toto you will have to provide a place holder inside your tamplate, something like `"Guess what? Exactly {srcName} , some even more..blahhh"` and then replace it using `replace()` which is a javascript function, I will try to help you with that tomorrow

Comment: @Toto I added more explanation for you, please make sure to upvote if it was helpful, and accept the answer if it is a correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Works a charm, just have to change my HTML template email around a bit to move the (click) to a more appropriate button. Also went and chained a few more replacements to allow for even more laziness. A shame though that it won't work right out of the box using interpolation :)

Comment: @Toto you can always ask me if you need any help :), an up vote would be great too, thanks

Comment: Tried to vote...sadly " Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."..